# Would a spinning particle in a spinning universe have spin?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, reference-frames, quantum-spin

Imagine a massless left-handed neutrino travelling along the x-axis with angular momentum 1/2.
Now change to a reference frame of a rotating universe on the same axis.

Someone in this reference frame would feel a force outwards towards the edge of the Universe.

But... would they see the neutrino have spin 0 ? (Or 50% 1/2 and 50% -1/2 angular momentum?)

i.e. would the angular momentum of the reference frame cancel out the spn of the particle?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Mach.

Comment: Are you trying to explain dark energy?

Comment: Also, "a particle with spin" is not the same thing as "a spinning particle". Spin is not a literal physical rotation.

Comment: Cool question. I took a look at the linked answer but it doesn't seem to say how a qubit transforms under rotations, which I've never seen. I've seen it for Dirac spinor fields, that's the closest...